# Partitioning a vector using std::partition

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector

I'm partitioning an array across a pivot. I tried the std::partition function:

```
partition(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), [&](int value) { return value < pivot; });
```

however I wish to include the pivot in the middle of the two sequences. How can I do this, either natively with std::partition or another method? I'm looking for performance here so solutions should be relatively fast.

Comment: This is the [Dutch National Flag Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest was is to make the pivot the last element of the sequence, call `std::partition()` with all but the last element, and if the mid-point is different from the partitioned end `swap()` the element in place:

```
sequence.push_back(pivot);
auto mid = std::partition(sequence.begin(), sequence.end() - 1,
                          [&](int value){ return value < pivot; });
if (mid != sequence.end() - 1) {
    std::swap(*mid, sequence.end()[-1]);
}
```

Adding the element first and `std::partition()`ing then rather than appending it after the `std::partition()` avoids the need of dealing with the sequence potentially being relocated.

If the `pivot` started out in the sequence, just first `std::swap()` it to the end and then `std::partition()`, followed by `std::swap()`ing it into the middle. If your objective is a *fat partition*, i.e., all element equal to the `pivot` should be in the middle, you'll need to `std::partition()` the second half accordingly. The standard C++ library doesn't have an algorithm which does a fat partition directly.

Comment: I receive a parameter type mismatch on line 5 on my system.

Comment: @CrazyPython: I fixed the code. Just a silly omission.

Comment: I should really compile example code... (fixed the other typoe, too)

Comment: Note to future viewers: for me I used `swap(sequence[pivot_pos], sequence.back());` because the pivot was already in the array.

Comment: Pardon this possibly really dumb question, but how could I find the index of the pivot after partition?

Comment: @CrazyPython: I'm not sure what you mean? `std::partition()` doesn't do anything special with the values being equality to a pivot. It can't really tell the pivot from any object which isn't smaller than pivot as the predicate is actually just a unary predicate. All it tell you is the end of the range of elements for which the predicate yields `true`. The indicated position is the first position a pivot would go.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `partition` a second time on the remaining elements.

```
auto point = partition(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(),
    [&](int value) { return value < pivot; });
partition(point, sequence.end(), [&](int value) { return value == pivot; });
```

I went ahead and implemented a three-way partition based on the algorithm here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem

```
template<typename IteratorT, typename ValueT>
std::pair<IteratorT, IteratorT>
three_way_partition(IteratorT _first, IteratorT _last, ValueT const& value) {
    auto i = _first;
    auto j = _first;
    auto k = _last - 1;
    while (j <= k) {
        if (*j < value) {
            std::swap(*i, *j);
            ++i;
            ++j;
        } else if (*j > value) {
            std::swap(*j, *k);
            --k;
        } else {
            ++j;
        }
    }

    return {i, j};
}
```

I tested it against the method of calling partition twice, and as I suspected, the difference in performance is negligible, and in fact, the partition twice method usually came out a little bit faster. Test it yourself and see.

Comment: This would double the computation time however.

Comment: @CrazyPython: Are you sure? Given a hypothetical function which did a three-way partition in one step, the comparison would have to make both checks anyway. And the placement logic would be more complicated. You could write such a function and compare it though. My bet is that you won't notice an advantage either way.